# Autofac - upgrading from .net core 2.2 to 3.1

Tags: autofac, .net-core-3.1

i'm following Autofac [guide](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#asp-net-core-3-0-and-generic-hosting) to migrate to .net 3.1

According to their guide, I need to add (among other things) this function:

```
public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
```

And this will be called automatically

The problem is that the code inside it that is registering the services is conditional for our app so I need to pass a boolean to the function

for example:

```
public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
 if (enableTokenAutoRefresh)
 {
   builder.RegisterType<AuthenticationWrapper>()
    .As<IApiProxy>()
 }
 else
 {
   builder.RegisterType<ApiProxy>()
    .As<IApiProxy>()
 }
}
```

Can I just add a boolean to the *ConfigureContainer* method?
seems this will break the calling for it?
and if not - how to pass data to it ?

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConfigureContainer`, provided by the ASP.NET Core framework, only takes the container builder type of your DI framework (in this case, an Autofac `ContainerBuilder`). To get additional data in there, you'd need to set a variable on the `Startup` class somewhere earlier in the startup pipeline and use it.

```cs
// NOT a complete Startup, but gives you the idea.
public class Startup
{
  public Startup(IConfiguration config)
  {
    // appSettings.json has the value you want
    this.EnableTokenAutoRefresh = config.GetValue<bool>("path:to:key");
  }

  public bool EnableTokenAutoRefresh { get; set; }

  public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
  {
    if(this.EnableTokenAutoRefresh)
    {
      // Do what you need to based on config
    }
  }
}
```